# I can't control dropdown list with codeigniter and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Dropdown list can't control in second field. I don't sure what's wrong.

My tables contain:

Table 1:

```
car (brand_id , car_brand)
```

Table 2:

```
model (model_id , brand_id , car_model)
```

This my code on Controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Front extends CI_Controller {

        public function myformAjax($id) { 
           $result = $this->db->where("brand_id",$id)->get("model")->result();
           echo json_encode($result);
       }
}?>
```

This my code on View.

```
<select name="sel_brands" id="sel_brands" class="form-control">

    <option value="" selected="selected">Brand</option>
    <?php foreach ($car as $count): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $count->brand_id; ?>"><?php echo $count->car_brand; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?> 


</select>



<select name="sel_model" id="sel_model" class="form-control">
        <option selected="selected" value=""> Model </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="sel_brands"]').on('change', function() {
            var brandID = $(this).val();
            if(brandID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>front/onlinecheck/ajax/'+brandID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="sel_model"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="sel_model"]').append('<option value="'+ value.model_id +'">'+ value.car_model +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="sel_model"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error? What does can't control mean?